# Flagged NAA, answer gets edited and flag gets declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I asked in [python chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=24287775#24287775) about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408272/get-file-creation-time-with-python-on-linux/1408281#1408281) to make sure it's considered a link-only-answer.

I flagged it as NAA. A few minutes later a user added some of the link content into the answer, making it an acceptable answer.

Why was my flag declined?

Comment: Moderators handle *loads* of flags. We don't always have time to verify each and every NAA flag to see if the question was edited in the interim. It's just one flag decline, don't sweat it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters quick check, the flag never made it into any  review queue for us mortals, right?

Comment: @rene: it doesn't look like it did. There was also a custom flag on it, declined at the same time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters tnx, that explains why I couldn't find it in SEDE (as these events happened more than a week ago).

Answer (score 2):

The likelihood is that, once content was added in, it ceased to be "not an answer".  I'm a bit surprised that it survived as long as it did, but that's besides the point; it is indeed something that appears to be an answer now instead of a plain link.

You should always flag content in the state that you see it in. Don't feel too bad if someone decides to change it between the time that you flag it and the time that it gets handled.

Comment: And a minor tip: if you catch a post in the first five minutes after it's been posted or last edited, make sure to comment in some fashion before flagging so a grace period edit won't make you look even sillier than is already the risk. (That is, a sufficiently careful reviewer can look at revisions to see that you had good reason to flag it, if you lock in the revision with a comment.)

Answer (score -3):

Seeing as that answer is currently the accepted answer with 24 upvotes, to a question with 17 upvotes, I'd say that the reason was that it was a good answer once the text was included in the question. The other user thought so too. This seems good, since now that question has a good answer. No?