# Why was my NAA flag declined if OP has edited the answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags, specific-answer

I have flagged [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63495351/revisions) as NAA at 21:46:05Z but the author has turned it into a proper answer at 22:01:24Z. My flag was declined 5 minutes ago.

If you edit a post in LQP thus salvaging it, then the flag is marked as helpful by the system, is it not? Why was my flag declined?

First revision:

> (Not enough Rep to Comment) Did you resolve this issue? Having same problem in a Spark job that works perfectly well via the Developer Endpoint.

Comment: That is some major turnaround of that Answer :O

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300191/#comment225766_300191). For some reason, Martijn decided to post it as a comment, not an answer. NAA flags aren't automatically dismissed and marked helpful by subsequent edits like VLQ flags are. Your NAA was reviewed by a mod and declined because, based on what they saw while reviewing it, the answer wasn't eligible for a NAA flag. The mod flag dashboard *does* now have an indicator that the answer has been edited since flagging, but it's one of many noisy elements on the dashboard, and easily overlooked for the bigger picture.